# Are continuous partial derivatives and Cauchy Riemann equations are sufficient for analyticity at a point?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a multiple select question.

Let $f = u+iv$ is defined in some neighbourhood of $z_0$ and that $u, v, u_x, v_x, u_y, u_y$ are continuous and satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations at $z_0$. Consider the following statements.

$1$: $f$ is analytic at $z_0$.

$2$: $f'(z_0)$ exists.

$3$: f is regular at $z_0$.

Choose the correct

$a-$ $1$ and $3$

$b-2$ and $3$

$c$-only $2$

$d$- $1, 2$ and $3$

This is my attempt.

If I take $f(z) = |z|^2$ then $f$ is differentiable only at $z=0$ and the partial derivatives are continuous. So $0$ is not a regular point. So $a$, $b$ and $d$ are discarded and therefore only $c$ is correct.

Is it correct? Answer sheet says that the answer is $d$.

Please confirm.

Comment: You are correct. Regularity and analyticity are local properties in the sense that if they apply to a point, they also apply to a neighborhood of that point. The given assumptions need not be local in this sense.